# Notification not comming 4.2.2 API 17

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using two Genymotion emulator. One with Android 4.1.1 and other with 4.2.2. Android 5.0 works the notification.

In the 4.2.2 the notification not arrive but the server says yes

{"multicast_id":6922075632436417470,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1455028566785442%2c62c465701c4188"}]}

This is what I send in the server

{"registration_ids":["cA-84oToSM0:APA91bEQ-N1PNvKgKKwpvZSVbUfQV3q6ZBGNrQYGfWqyxNkguiOBztxCpNVkhoAyT53KsPq9j40XcqxvNf0JZAPdJZJME10XTqZRuNYGL3yabOVA1XI69EuGlUO9K4Duktoi0leLL_DK"],"data":{"title":"Ejemplo de push","message":"Esto es homesolution y te mandaron un mensaje","ticker_text":"Mensaje HS de Juan"},"collapse_key":"homesolution_topic","delay_while_idle":false}

**delay_while_idle I test in true and false**

The server is OK, the android app is OK, google play services are update

if I uninstall the app and install again, the push arrive but the notification bar is broken (I cant swipe down). If I turn off-turn on, with the same gcm_id, the push is not comming

Any help? Thanks!

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "Test/Registration";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
            // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
            // [START get_token]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // [END get_token]
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // Save the registration token in a global variable
            // When a user is registered or logged this will be used
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        final Global global = (Global) getApplicationContext();
        global.setGcmId(token);
        Log.d(TAG, "Registration token saved as => " + token);
    }

}
```

Comment: provide `BroadcastReceiver` code and notification sender server code..

Comment: the GCM Registration Token is ok, I have it

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16764422/4848308

Comment: definitely you should check this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/CimKwgaf2ws

Comment: if U read my post, I have already set delay_while_idle in false and before was in true.